# Changing background color of a specific row in slickgrid?

Tags: javascript, css, slickgrid

is there any way to change the background color of a specific row in slickgrid table while leaving other as it is ??? i'm using

```
for ( var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    rowIndex[i] = {
        price : "editable-col",
        qty : "editable-col",
        ccy : "buy-row",
        side : "buy-col",
        symbol : "buy-row",
        enable : "buy-row"
    };
}
grid.setCellCssStyles("", rowIndex);
```

where "editable-col" , "buy-row" & "buy-col" are the CSS classes containing the color setting properties for background/foreground etc. whenever i want to change the background color of a specific row , i have to change to color of whole grid(by looping through grid length) , or if i set class for a specific row e.g.

```
rowIndex[5] = {
    price : "editable-col",
    qty : "editable-col",
    ccy : "buy-row",
    side : "buy-col",
    symbol : "buy-row",
    enable : "buy-row"
};
grid.setCellCssStyles("", rowIndex);
```

it sets the css class for the desired row but clear all css properties for other rows , to avoid this i need to reset the css classes for the other rows too which is i think not good in terms of performance and time when you have thousands of rows. just want to know is there any better way to do this without touching the other rows. ?? any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming you're using `Slick.Data.DataView`, you can modify the [`getItemMetadata` method](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView) to dynamically add classes to the containing row element. You can then simply setup your grid to change the row's style based on some value inside the row. Assuming your `Slick.Data.DataView` instance is called `dataView`:

```js
dataView.getItemMetadata = metadata(dataView.getItemMetadata);

function metadata(old_metadata) {
  return function(row) {
    var item = this.getItem(row);
    var meta = old_metadata(row) || {};

    if (item) {
      // Make sure the "cssClasses" property exists
      meta.cssClasses = meta.cssClasses || '';

      if (item.canBuy) {                    // If the row object has a truthy "canBuy" property
        meta.cssClasses += ' buy-row';      // add a class of "buy-row" to the row element.
      } // Note the leading ^ space.

      if (item.qty < 1) {                   // If the quantity (qty) for this item less than 1
        meta.cssClasses += ' out-of-stock'; // add a class of "out-of-stock" to the row element.
      }

   /* Here is just a random example that will add an HTML class to the row element
      that is the value of your row's "rowClass" property. Be careful with this as
      you may run into issues if the "rowClass" property isn't a string or isn't a
      valid class name. */
      if (item.rowClass) {
        var myClass = ' '+item.rowClass;
        meta.cssClasses += myClass;
      }
    }

    return meta;
  }
}
```

This will allow you to dynamically add the "buy-row" class to the row. You can change the function to have multiple conditions for different classes, just remember that the CSS classes for every row will be conditional based on the row object properties. The `ret.cssClasses` is the key here. It is the string that'll get output in the row HTML: `<div class="[ret.cssClasses]">`.

You can now do something like this to change a row's classes:

```js
var row = dataView.getItem(5);

row.canBuy = true;
dataView.updateItem(row.id, row);
// The row element should now have a class of "buy-row" on it.

row.canBuy = false;
row.qty = 0;
dataView.updateItem(row.id, row);
// It should now have a class of "out-of-stock" and the "buy-row" class should be gone.

row.qty = 10;
row.rowClass = 'blue';
dataView.updateItem(row.id, row);
// It should now have a class of "blue" and the "out-of-stock" class should be gone.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one way is to simply use jQuery:

```
var rowNumber = 3;
$($('.grid-canvas').children()[rowNumber]).css('background-color','red');
```

**Update**

To have persistent highlighting you need to implement the getItemMetadata function. It can be done like this:

html

```
<div style="width:600px;">
    <div id="myGrid" style="width:100%;height:500px;"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.highlight{
    background-color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

javascript

```
var grid;
var columns = [
    {id: "title", name: "Title", field: "title"},
    {id: "duration", name: "Duration", field: "duration"},
    {id: "%", name: "% Complete", field: "percentComplete"},
    {id: "start", name: "Start", field: "start"},
    {id: "finish", name: "Finish", field: "finish"},
    {id: "effort-driven", name: "Effort Driven", field: "effortDriven"}
];

var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    data[i] = {
        title: "Task " + i,
        duration: "5 days",
        percentComplete: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
        start: "01/01/2009",
        finish: "01/05/2009",
        effortDriven: (i % 5 == 0)
    };
}
data.getItemMetadata = function (row) {

    if (this[row].title == 'Task 5'){
        return {
            cssClasses: 'highlight'

        };

    }
    return null;

}
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, { enableColumnReorder: false });
```

Comment: That won't retain the CSS once the row goes out of view. SlickGrid re-uses the same row elements when scrolling or paginating and will overwrite the styles associated with them.

Comment: has problem with grouping