# Way to set global font size in slickgrid

Tags: css, html, slickgrid

I'd like to be able to scale font size up across the board in slickgrid. It would appear that this is doable via style sheets etc, but not programmatically set a font size to use.

I've tried setting rowHeight in options, and then just apply a style in css to the rows themselves, but the text is always offset (because line height).

Is there any easy way of being able to just say use this font size and have the grid handle the rest? (I dont need variable row heights / font size, just be able to dynamically set it before rendering)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the followings CSS changes, make sure to load that CSS file at the end so it doesn't get overwritten

```
.grid .grid-canvas .slick-cell {
  padding: 5px 7.5834px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.grid .grid-canvas .slick-cell td {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.grid .slick-header-columns .slick-header-column {
  height: 33px;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  /* like TH  */

  background: transparent;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
}
.grid .slick-header-columns .slick-header-column.ui-state-default {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
}
.grid .slick-header-columns .slick-header-column.ui-state-default td {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

If you want to change these settings dynamically after a page load, you might want to try putting all of these CSS in jQuery calls, though that might be ugly.. :S

If you want to change just 1 cell in particular, then you'll have to deal with SlickGrid metadata as shown in this answer here: [Changing background color of a specific row in slickgrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887575/changing-background-color-of-a-specific-row-in-slickgrid)

Comment: While I dont think this is hugely wrong, my problem is that I want to say use small/medium/large or specific font sizes, and have it use that for existing rows, or rows it dynamically builds. So when I say global I mean global, but global dynamically

Comment: Ah yeah that's a bit touchy to do, but I guess you'll have to replicate 3x the CSS I've put with an extra property (small,medium,large) in your CSS...perhaps something like this: `.slick-cell-small{ font-size: 8px; }` then maybe add this class (with a button click) into your elements with this: `$('.slick-cell').addClass('slick-cell-small')` ... haven't tried it though, but I intend to use that as well later or sooner

Comment: The problem with this is that I cant easily swap it out via say a configuration. I do however think this comment is valuable for others that might come across this answer as a solution to a different problem

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a working solution....

Basically I just created 3 css styles small medium large xlarge. I have row heights setup for those sizes as well.

When initializing the slick grid I set rowsize and then initialize the dataView like so:

```
dataView.getItemMetadata = function(idx) {
        return {cssClasses: config.rowSize}
};
```

Basically applying the style of the same name to every row in the same slickgrid. Sucks I have to specify the actual rowheight in the actual initialization of slickgrid (vs just using something from css but what are you going to do.)

Comment: So I guess that is basically what I suggest before with 3 files? Would you mind posting the part of CSS which you change... I'd like to see which CSS properties needs to change all in all... thx