# Slickgrid GetItemMetadata function refers only to the last item #563

Tags: javascript, slickgrid, dataview

I am trying to change the style of several rows with the following code block:

```js
DV.getItemMetadata = function (row) {
  let description = this.getItem(row).Description;

  if (description != null) {
    return {
      cssClasses: 'notify'
    };
  }
  return null;
};
```

Here I can see that this is done correctly for all elements, but only the last element is colored.

Comment: are you sure that the `this` refers to the Slick DataView object? And also don't forget that JavaScript is case sensitive, I'm saying this because you use `Description` with uppercase. in my case I use it like this `const item = dataView.getItem(rowNumber);`, it's easier to debug and add console log to just deal with the item dataContext, make sure u get something then only after use the `item.Description` to read its description

Comment: I can confirm that "this" indeed points to the DataView object, also that I get the correct value, the colors are also set correctly as described, only they are lost again, except for the last element for which the condition applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what your problem is but I'm showing you the code that works for me, please note that it's written with ES6 (TypeScript) syntax and you might need to change it a bit if you want to keep ES5 syntax.

The example I got working has this code

```js
  /** Change the Duration Rows Background Color */
  changeDurationBackgroundColor() {
    this.dataView.getItemMetadata = this.updateItemMetadataForDurationOver40(this.dataView.getItemMetadata);

    // also re-render the grid for the styling to be applied right away
    this.grid.invalidate();
    this.grid.render();
  }

  /**
   * Change the SlickGrid Item Metadata, we will add a CSS class on all rows with a Duration over 50
   * For more info, you can see this SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/19985148/1212166
   */
  updateItemMetadataForDurationOver50(previousItemMetadata: any) {
    const newCssClass = 'duration-bg';

    return (rowNumber: number) => {
      const item = this.dataView.getItem(rowNumber);
      let meta = {
        cssClasses: ''
      };
      if (typeof previousItemMetadata === 'object') {
        meta = previousItemMetadata(rowNumber);
      }

      if (meta && item && item.duration) {
        const duration = +item.duration; // convert to number
        if (duration > 50) {
          meta.cssClasses = (meta.cssClasses || '') + ' ' + newCssClass;
        }
      }

      return meta;
    };
  }
```

then once you call the `changeDurationBackgroundColor()` from a button click it changes the background color for every row with a duration over 50.

You can also try it yourself, here's the live [Demo](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/additem)

Hopefully that can help you find your problem, you might be missing the `grid.invalidate()` after the metadata has changed?

[image]